# Deserialize an Object with Camel-Netty4

Tags: sockets, apache-camel, deserialization, netty, decoder

At the client side I have a working-fine socket sending a Java Object:

```
Detail detail = new Detail(); //client object
Socket client = new Socket(host, port);
OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
oos.writeObject(detail);
oos.flush();
```

Note: this is the client socket so cannot be changed.

At the server side I have **camel-2.14.1 + Spring + netty4**, running in **Jboss AS7**, which has this simple consumer rute:

```
from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:6549?"+ 
     "keepAlive=true&sync=true&decoder=#detailDecoder&encoder=#detailEncoder")
  .log("server recive: ${body.getArea}")
  .processRef("someDetailProcessor") //loaded with Spring
  .log("response [${body.getArea}]");
```

I already realized I cant use `StringDecoder/StringEncoder` to deserialize/serialize Objects because this encoders are waiting for more plain-text like messages.

Due this reason I ended up using `ObjectDecoder/ObjectEncoder` injecting them like this:

```
<bean id="objDecoder" class="org.apache.camel.component.netty4.ChannelHandlerFactories" factory-method="newObjectDecoder">
    <constructor-arg name="protocol" value="tcp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="objEncoder" class="org.apache.camel.component.netty4.ChannelHandlerFactories" factory-method="newObjectEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="protocol" value="tcp"/>
</bean>
```

But my object is exceeding the frame length max, throwing the exception -

```
Closing channel as an exception was thrown from Netty. Caused by: [io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException - Adjusted frame length exceeds 1048576: 2901213193 - discarded]
```

I have tried to setup `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` (which is the superclass of `ObjectDecoder` and also expects an integer header field that represents the length of the message body, so no usefull). I've used also `ByteToMessageDocoder` in different ways (by creating my own class and trying to decode the `ByteBuf` into a Detail) but with no lucky at all.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I just need to receive a simple object, shouldn't be that hard, should it be?

Comment: Well, by reading more the documentation I found on ObjectDecoder: "Please note that the serialized form this decoder expects is not compatible with the standard **`ObjectOutputStream`**. Please use **`ObjectEncoder`** or **`ObjectEncoderOutputStream`** to ensure the interoperability with this decoder.".....I'm using ObjectOutputStream to send the object :(
ahhhh, I'm almost there!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after struggling a bit with this I came up with one workaround:

I decided to use **`ReplayingDecoder`** instead of `ObjectDecoder` and  `ByteToMessageDecoder` because:

1. `ObjectDecoder` is not compatible with `ObjectOutputStream` ([quote](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/serialization/ObjectDecoder.html))
2. `ByteToMessaDecoder`

   - You need to check if there are enough bytes ready to read on the input `ByteBuf` before you do the actual read operation. (quote from Netty in Action)
   - Frame detection should be handled earlier in the pipeline by adding another decoder. ([quote](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html))
   - Some methods such as `ByteBuf.readBytes(int)` will cause a memory leak if the returned buffer is not released or added to the out List. ([quote](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/ByteToMessageDecoder.html))
   - And finally because it gave me worse average times during testing compared with `ReplayingDecoder`. Maybe because its usage of `ByteBuf`.

ReplayingDecoder has also some limitations (both quoted from Netty in Action):

1. Not all operations on the `ByteBuf` are supported, and if you call an unsupported operation, it will throw an `UnreplayableOperationException`.
2. `ByteBuf.readableBytes()` wont return what you expect most of the time.

So as I don't know how the end of messages look like (if I would it'd be suitable [DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html)), neither the length of every arrival package ([as it's said in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564090/4056187)), then I ended up grouping the bytes, doing something like this:

```java
// to collect the object bytes
private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

    if(in.isReadable()){

        // wrIdx - rdIdx instead of .readableBytes()
        byte[] frame = new byte[in.writerIndex()-in.readerIndex()];

        // I read just what I get, so the signal is never thrown
        in.readBytes(frame);

        // collecting bytes
        baos.write(frame);

        // it'll achieve this only when all the bytes from
        // the incoming object have been collected
        try{
            out.add(SerializationUtils.deserialize(baos.toByteArray()));
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

**TODO**:

- I might need something better than `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils` to deserialize
- what if the deserialized object is not the type I need. How can I discard it?

Hope this can help someone!